# double every value of dictionary

Tags: python, list, google-bigquery

I want to double every value of dictionary (only double the value, do not change the key).
I tried with the update()` method and normally multiply with 2 with its value.

```
# Sol 1: 
dict1 = {"dhoni":50,"jadeja":45,"kohli":60}
dict1["dhoni"]= 100
dict1["jadeja"]= 90
dict1["kohli"]= 120
print(dict1)

# sol 2: 
dict2= {"dhoni":50,"jadeja":45,"kohli":60}
dict2["dhoni"]= 50*2
dict2["jadeja"]= 45*2
dict2["kohli"]= 60*2
print(dict2)

# sol 3: 

dict3 = {"dhoni":50,"jadeja":45,"kohli":60}
x=dict3.values()
dict3["dhoni"]=100
dict3["jadeja"]=90
dict3["kohli"]=120
print(dict3)
```

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Comment: I dont see how solution 1 and 3 are different, nor do i see what you're asking for

Comment: Your code does not use the update method at all. Needs more detail & clarity what your exact problem with the update method is.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you need.

```
dict1 = {"dhoni":50,"jadeja":45,"kohli":60}
new_dict = dict({k: 2*v for k,v in dict1.items()})
```

```
Output:

new_dict = {'dhoni': 100, 'jadeja': 90, 'kohli': 120}
```

If you want to update `dict1` inplace, then:

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    dict1[k] = 2*v
```

```
Output:

dict1 = {'dhoni': 100, 'jadeja': 90, 'kohli': 120}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m asuming you want to double them all and all values are either int or floats.

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    dictionary[key] = value * 2
```

Edit:
As you have multiple dictionaries you could add these to a list.

```
dict_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

for dict in dict_list:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        dictionary[key] = value * 2
```